# Need to trump generated inline css

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I am working on editing our intranet site and basically all I am able to change is the CSS. Although I have gotten it to look like I want with these limitations, I have one little snag. If I was told correctly, the html is generated via a .aspx file, and in this html is the inline CSS applied to the navigation menu of

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

When I preview it in Chrome and Firefox it works fine, but when I view it in IE10, the navigation is pushed to the left. If I disable it using the developer tools, it works fine, but I can't access the html since it is generated, so I can't, at lease as far as I know, create a rule that can trump it. I have zero experience with ASP, but I have opened the file and looked through it, but it's all greek to me. Any thoughts? TIA!

Comment: Can you show me your url where problem exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `!important` in your stylesheet to override the inline value, like this:

Inline style:

```
<div style="background: red;">
    The inline styles for this div should make it red.
</div>
```

Stylesheet:

```
div[style] {
    background: yellow !important;
}
```

Note: This will result in a div with a yellow background, even though the inline style said for the background to be red.

Comment: Thanks! You just saved me a LOT of time!